# How to setup the rewrite engine in VisualSVN Server

Tags: svn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server, apache-modules

We need to redirect all write actions to another repository.

For example:

```
 Repository we are using : https://<Server_ip1>/svn/Projects/

 Redirect Repository      : https://<Server_ip2>/svn/Projects/
```

All write actions on the `https://"Server_ip1"/svn/Projects/` repository need to redirect to the `https://"Server_ip"/svn/Projects/` repository.

Any ideas about how this can be done?